# How does op-amp gain = 1 - error?

Tags: operational-amplifier, unity-gain

Please see attached image. How does the voltage gain end up being equivalent to Av = 1-error?

Thanks
[image: Question]
[image: Solution]

Comment: It is hardly readable. Please, make an effort and rewrite the question using the built-in schematic and formula engines..

Comment: Oh. I'm not too sure how to use them, especially the formula engines. Apologies

Comment: [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Are you asking why \$\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \approx 1 - \epsilon \:\$?

Comment: Nope, I was confused on how to actually derive the error term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your question is how do you get from:

$$A_v = \frac{1}{1+\frac{R_{out}+R_L}{A_oR_L}} \tag{1}$$

To:

$$A_v \approx 1 - \frac{R_{out}+R_L}{A_oR_L}$$

It is an approximation rather than an equality. Let's examine it.

First we will say:

$$x = \frac{R_{out}+R_L}{A_oR_L} \tag{2}$$

Substituting (2) into (1), we get:

$$\frac{1}{1+x} = (1+x)^{-1}$$

Using the Binomial expansion of this (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210110/whats-the-name-of-the-approximation-1xn-approx-1-xn)), we basically get:

$$\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + ... $$

This is where we make an approximation. If \$x\$ is very small (i.e. \$x<<1\$), then it follows \$x^2\$ and \$x^3\$ and so on, are going to be very very small. So small that we make an approximation that they are negligible. As a result, we can say:

$$\frac{1}{1+x} \approx 1 - x \tag{3}$$

Substituting (1) and (2) into (3), we then get:

$$A_v \approx 1 - \frac{R_{out}+R_L}{A_oR_L}$$